# how to remove these empty lines

Tags: c++, removing-whitespace

i can detect the empty line in text but not getting how to delete it
 please can you give me some tips how to delete that detected lines

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

// open input file

    std::ifstream ifs( "in_f1.txt" );
    std::fstream ofs( "out_f1.txt" );
    char c;
    char previous_c;

// squeeze whitespace

   std::string word;
   ifs >> word;
   ofs << word;

   while (ifs)
    {
        if (c==' ')
        {
         ofs.put(c);
           while (c==' '&&ifs)
           {
            ifs.get (c);
              ;}
           }
             if (c=='\v')
        {
           previous_c=c;
           while (c=='\v'&&ifs)
           {
              ifs.get (c);
              ;}
            ofs.put(previous_c);
           };

// read line

    std::string line;
    std::getline( ofs, line );

// append flag and remove 'empty lines'

    int flag = 2;

    while( getline( ofs, line ) )
    {
        if( line == " " )
        {
            flag = 2;
            continue;
        }
        cout << line << " " << flag << endl;
        flag = 0;
    }

ifs.close();
ofs.close();

}}
```

Comment: Do you want to detect duplicate lines too?

Comment: Create a new file, write all the text except for the text that you want to delete to that new file, remove the original file and rename the new file to your original file.

Comment: Your indentation is whack. You do not set `c` before accessing it. What if the first line in the file is blank?

Comment: @Poldie no only these empty line , thank you guys very much ,

Answer (score 1):

you are looking in the output stream for an empty line, **after** you copy the characters to it.. A stream is not intended to be something we edit like a string, so stop thinking on it that way..

instead you need to add the logic before you put the characters into the stream.

the easiest approach is to have a temporary stream, that you copy from input to.

then for each line, copy the temporary stream to output stream, if and only if, it contains characters different from whitespace.

Comment: There's no need for a temporary stream, just use a `std::string`

Comment: actually i am new in c++ just start learning thank you guys very much, i will try to do that way

Comment: you really should look at the answer by @JonathanWakely, using a **std::string**. and give him the accepted answer!
It reads the contents of the input stream, between newlines, and places those characters in a string. strings can be manipulated easily, or tested for empty. - he does this, and then transfers the characters to the output stream, if the line is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
void remove_empty_lines(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out)
{
  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(in, line))
    if (!line.empty())
      out << line << '\n';
}
```

N.B. This will add a newline to the end of the file even if there isn't one in the original.

Comment: it just giving the first word from input file, output file , i didn't understand why

Comment: Then you're using it wrong. Open the two fstream objects, pass them to the function. That's all. Nothing else.